# Oracle generating time INTERVAL without crossing next day

Tags: oracle, datetime, intervals

I also have a way to generate dates with times using an internal. I know I can use CONNECT by level <=N but that would require me manually editing N for each interval, which I'm trying to avoid.

What I like to do is populate each date in a range with a series of times based on an interval that starts at midnight and doesn't go past 23:59:59 for each date.  if the time goes past midnight I want to start incrementing for the next day at midnight..

For example, below stops incrementing at 01112022 03:20:00
when I would like it to stop at 01112022 23:50:00

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'MMDDYYYY HH24:MI:SS';


select to_date ( 
'01-11-2022','mm-dd-yyyy' ) +  numtodsinterval(rownum*10,'MINUTE')
    from dual
    connect by level <= 20;

01112022 00:10:00
01112022 00:20:00
01112022 00:30:00
01112022 00:40:00
01112022 00:50:00
01112022 01:00:00
01112022 01:10:00
01112022 01:20:00
01112022 01:30:00
01112022 01:40:00
01112022 01:50:00
01112022 02:00:00
01112022 02:10:00
01112022 02:20:00
01112022 02:30:00
01112022 02:40:00
01112022 02:50:00
01112022 03:00:00
01112022 03:10:00
01112022 03:20:00
```

Comment: Your requirements are unclear to me - your example has only 20 rows, and therefore, it spans only 190 minutes ((20 - 1) * 10 min).  If you use 200 instead of 20, it wraps around (after 2022-01-11 23:50:00, you get 2022-01-12 00:00:00).

As a side note, your date format makes my head hurt :-)

Comment: It's a bit hard to decipher, but it sounds like you want to calculate the *N* based on the interval size? In which case, is the interval always defined in minutes, and the`10` is really a variable; and you'll always start at midnight, not part way through a day? Also don't you want to include '01112022 00:00:00' in the result in your example?

Comment: In your example, why is the first time you generate 00:10:00 and not 00:00:00? Your own small example doesn't seem to mach the requirement you described. Then: In addition to the interval (10 minutes, which you say should be a variable), you need to also state what the first and the last date-times should be. Or, if it's for full days, you should state from which start date to which end date. And also tell us HOW you are presenting these variables to the query. (Best: as bind variables, but your requirement may be different.)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to specify N with an exact number of intervals, you can use a start date/end date logic to generate the intervals.

```sql
    SELECT DATE '2022-01-11' + NUMTODSINTERVAL (LEVEL * 10, 'MINUTE')
      FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY DATE '2022-01-11' + NUMTODSINTERVAL (LEVEL * 10, 'MINUTE') < DATE '2022-01-12';
```

Comment: thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

This is a nice *use case* for a *recursive CTE*.

```
with dt (dt, interv) as (
select date '2022-01-11', numtodsinterval(10,'MINUTE') from dual
union all
select dt.dt + interv, interv from dt
where dt.dt + interv <  trunc(dt.dt)+1)
select dt from dt;

DT                 
-------------------
11.01.2022 00:00:00
11.01.2022 00:10:00
11.01.2022 00:20:00
.....
11.01.2022 23:50:00
```

Note that I added the *interval* as a column, so you need not the repeat it twice in the query.

The *start date* and *interval* are used only *once* in the query, so you may them easily configure.

To generate a sequence *over more than one day* simple add the column `stop` with the *end date*.

```
with dt (dt, interv, stop) as (
select date '2022-01-11', numtodsinterval(10,'MINUTE'), date '2022-01-13' from dual
union all
select dt.dt + interv, interv, stop from dt
where dt.dt + interv <   stop)
select * from dt;

DT                  INTERV              STOP               
------------------- ------------------- -------------------
11.01.2022 00:00:00 +00 00:10:00.000000 13.01.2022 00:00:00
11.01.2022 00:10:00 +00 00:10:00.000000 13.01.2022 00:00:00
11.01.2022 00:20:00 +00 00:10:00.000000 13.01.2022 00:00:00
11.01.2022 00:30:00 +00 00:10:00.000000 13.01.2022 00:00:00
. . .
12.01.2022 23:40:00 +00 00:10:00.000000 13.01.2022 00:00:00
12.01.2022 23:50:00 +00 00:10:00.000000 13.01.2022 00:00:00

288 rows selected.
```

Comment: if I wanted 2 days in my range and wanted to cross midnight will this work?    with dt (dt, interv) as (
select date '2022-01-11', numtodsinterval(30,'MINUTE') from dual
union all
select dt.dt + interv, interv from dt
where dt.dt + interv <  trunc(dt.dt)+2)
select dt from dt;

Comment: Nope, this *trick* works for one day only. Use instead e.g. `where dt.dt + interv <   date '2022-01-12'` to limit the end for more days. If your *interval* divides the day without an remainder, it will work for more days as you *cross the days on midnight* as you requested. @Pugzly

Comment: perfect. Thanks. Sorry for the confusion